# Haciendo un piedra,papel o tijera en JS

Tags: javascript

Tenía este codigo, donde mi problema era que la funcion `playRound` funcionaba pero con los valores de la ronda anterior.Aqui el codigo:

```js
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){ 
    choice();   
        //If player win
    if ((playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") || (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") || (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper")){
        return `The player won! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;  
     
    }  //If computer win
    else if ((playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "paper") || (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "rock") || (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "scissors")){
        return `The computer won!  ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;  
    }   // If its a tie
    else {
        return "It´s a tie!";
    }
}

function choice (){
    
    playerSelection = prompt("Que opcion elegis? Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
    playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
    computerSelection = computerPlay();
    console.log(`The computer chose: ${computerSelection}`);
    console.log(`You chose: ${playerSelection}`);
    
} 

function computerPlay() {
    const options = ["scissors" , "rock" , "paper"];
        return options[Math.floor(Math.random()* options.length)];
}


let playerSelection;
let computerSelection;

for (let i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
    
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
}
```

Aqui un ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo solucione poniendo llamando a la función `choice` dentro del loop `for`. Aqui se puede observar:

```js
function playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection){ 
    
        //If player win
    if ((playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") || (playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "scissors") || (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper")){
        return `The player won! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;  
     
    }  //If computer win
    else if ((playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "paper") || (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "rock") || (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "scissors")){
        return `The computer won!  ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;  
    }   // If its a tie
    else {
        return "It´s a tie!";
    }
}

function choice (){
    
    playerSelection = prompt("Que opcion elegis? Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
    playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
    computerSelection = computerPlay();
    console.log(`The computer chose: ${computerSelection}`);
    console.log(`You chose: ${playerSelection}`);
    
} 

function computerPlay() {
    const options = ["scissors" , "rock" , "paper"];
        return options[Math.floor(Math.random()* options.length)];
}


let playerSelection;
let computerSelection;

for (let i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
    choice();   
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
}
```

Mi pregunta es si alguien me puede explicar porque pasa eso? Porque no es posible (en este caso) poner la funcion `choice` dentro de la funcion `playRound`? Ya que si el contenido de `choice` lo ubico dentro de `playRound` funciona perfectamente.
Desde ya muchas gracias

Answer (score 3):

La razón del comportamiento que mencionas se entiende cuando comprendes el concepto de ['scope' o 'alcance' en Javascript](https://somospnt.com/blog/120-scope-en-javascript#:%7E:text=El%20scope%20de%20una%20variable,cada%20parte%20de%20nuestro%20c%C3%B3digo.) así como la mutabilidad de variables.

Ojo también que tu código tiene un detalle que puede haberte confundido mas, y es el hecho de que los nombres de tus variables para guardar las jugadas tienen el mismo nombre que los parámetros que recibe tu función `playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)`. Esta congruencia de nombres hace que cuando estés dentro del **scope** de `playRound(...)`, las variables `playerSelection` y `computerSelection` tendrán los valores con los que se llamó la función, y no los valores nuevos que setea `choice`.

Es por eso que cuando `choice()` estaba dentro de `playRound(...)`, la primera iteración de tu `for` llamaba a `playRound()` siendo `playerSelection` y `computerSelection` `undefined`, haciendo que las comparaciones después del choice fueran nulas, pero a la siguiente iteración se llamaba denuevo `playRound()` con los valores cambiados por el `choice()` de la iteración anterior, y así hasta el fin de tu ciclo.

Así mismo, cuando pones el `choice()` en el loop antes de llamar a `playRound()`, las variables mutan correctamente haciendo que cuando se llame `playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection)` ambos parámetros ya tengan un valor.

**Edit:**

Para comprobar que el problema está en los nombres de los parámetros y no en la definición de las variables del scope global, puedes conservar tu primer intento y eliminar los parámetros de la función `playRound()` quedando así:

```js
function playRound(){ 
    choice()
        //If player win
if ((playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "rock") || (playerSelection === "rock" &&   computerSelection === "scissors") || (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "paper")){
        return `The player won! ${playerSelection} beats ${computerSelection}`;  
     
    }  //If computer win
    else if ((playerSelection === "rock" && computerSelection === "paper") || (playerSelection === "scissors" && computerSelection === "rock") || (playerSelection === "paper" && computerSelection === "scissors")){
        return `The computer won!  ${computerSelection} beats ${playerSelection}`;  
    }   // If its a tie
    else {
        return "It´s a tie!";
    }
}

function choice (){
    
    playerSelection = prompt("Que opcion elegis? Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
    playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
    computerSelection = computerPlay();
    console.log(`The computer chose: ${computerSelection}`);
    console.log(`You chose: ${playerSelection}`);
    
} 

function computerPlay() {
    const options = ["scissors" , "rock" , "paper"];
        return options[Math.floor(Math.random()* options.length)];
}


let playerSelection;
let computerSelection;

for (let i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
    console.log(playRound());
}
```

O si cambias los nombres de los parámetros de la función `playRound(...)`, queda más notorio el problema

```js
function playRound(player, computer){ 
    choice()
    // Aca player y computer tienen los valores con que se llamó la función
    // y no los valores que mutó choice() que son playerSelection y computerSelection

    //If player win
    if ((player === "paper" && computer === "rock") || (player === "rock" && computer === "scissors") || (player === "scissors" && computer === "paper")){
        return `The player won! ${player} beats ${computer}`;  
    }
      //If computer win
    else if ((player === "rock" && computer === "paper") || (player === "scissors" && computer === "rock") || (player === "paper" && computer === "scissors")){
        return `The computer won!  ${computer} beats ${player}`;  
    }
    // If its a tie
    else {
        return "It´s a tie!";
    }
}

function choice (){
    
    playerSelection = prompt("Que opción elegís? Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
    playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();
    computerSelection = computerPlay();
    console.log(`The computer chose: ${computerSelection}`);
    console.log(`You chose: ${playerSelection}`);
    
} 

function computerPlay() {
    const options = ["scissors" , "rock" , "paper"];
        return options[Math.floor(Math.random()* options.length)];
}


let playerSelection;
let computerSelection;

for (let i = 0 ; i < 5; i++){
    console.log(playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection));
}
```

Comment: Hay las variables no tendrian un scope global al ser declaradas fuera de la funcion o tambien se tiene en cuenta cuando se le asigna un contenido?

Comment: Efectivamente, las variables declaradas en el mismo scope donde se define la función hace que dentro del su scope se pueda tambien llamar y mutar la variables de 'afuera'. El problema está en que los nombres de los parámetros de ua función se sobreponen sobre los nombres que se heredan, en ell caso que se llamen igual. Modifiqué la respuesta para mostrarte mejor